# Calculation of cardinality of Jacobians

Tags: computational-complexity, algebraic-curves, finite-fields

The problem of calculation the number of rational points on curves over finite fields is $\#P$-complete - ["Counting curves and their  projections"](https://cosec.bit.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/user_upload/publications/pubs/gatkar93.pdf).

Is it true for calculation of number of rational points of Jacobians?

Comment: I do not know what the #P complexity class is. In any case, the computations of the zeta functions of a curve and of its jacobian are essentially equivalent, and are equivalent to the computation of the number of points of $X$  in all finite extensions of the ground finite field of degree less than the genus of the curve.

Comment: @ACL >the computations of the zeta functions of a curve and of its jacobian are essentially equivalent.


I do not think that this is true in terms of computational complexity. For some curves we can compute number of $\mathbb{F}_3$-rational points of their Jacobians but we do not know such algorithms for computing  characteristic polynomials of Frobenius - http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/ants2.pdf